# Why do we go for objects in Javascript when arrays themselves can hold heterogeneous types of data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm new to JavaScript and I got this awkward doubt when I went through the concepts of objects in JavaScript, since the disadvantage of arrays in most of the programming languages is that it can hold only homogeneous datatypes. But that is not the case in JS. So why not we use arrays instead of objects in JS?

Comment: Because array items can only be accessed by numeric index, whereas object property values can be accessed by string key, and being able to use collections indexed by a string key is useful.

Comment: In javascript, Arrays are nothing but an object.
typeof Array()   //'object'

Comment: Sure, you *could* make an array of heterogeneous values, but how do you access those values then and how do you know which is which? Typically you access specific named properties on an object, while you loop over an arbitrary number of items in an array. It seems to be self-explanatory that one would hold heterogeneous data and the other homogeneous data.

Comment: @AZ_ Arrays are more than just objects in JavaScript, since they come with a lot of "prepackaged" functionality. Using objects where you should be using arrays has as much code smell as the other way around.

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen, I do understand that Thankyou, but thought its worth to mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array should be used when you have to access values a specific order or want looping through , if you don't care about the key name go with array or if you are concerned with value should be accessed with string key then objects are best .